# Mongoose Cannot Post Data Twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make a simple blog app. I can get the app to submit content to the DB on the first attempt, but if you try a second time Node crashes. I cannot figure out why.

post.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

PostSchema = new Schema({title: {type: String, "default": ''},
                         content: {type: String, "default": ''}});

Post = mongoose.model('posts', PostSchema);

module.exports.Post = Post;
module.exports.PostSchema = PostSchema;
```

db-conn.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Post = require('./post').Post;

var createPost = function(newTitle, newContent){
    mongoose.connection.once('open', function(){
        var p = new Post({ title: newTitle,
                           content: newContent });
        p.save(function(err){
          if (err) throw err;
        });
     });

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@(myIP):27017/blog', function(err){
      if (err) throw err;
    });

    mongoose.disconnect();
};

module.exports.createPost = createPost;
```

And then in my server.js file I just receive the title and content from the page and pass them to db-conn.js.  Like I said, the first time you run createPost it runs successfully. 2nd attempt crashes. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong with your code so I just copied it and commented it.

```
var createPost = function(newTitle, newContent){
    mongoose.connection.once('open', function(){
        var p = new Post({ title: newTitle,
                           content: newContent });
        p.save(function(err){
          if (err) throw err;
        });
     });

    // This should only be happening once, usually during application setup.
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@(myIP):27017/blog', function(err){
      if (err) throw err;
    });

    // You almost never need to call this yourself, but even if this call was
    // legit it should not be called immediately after `connect`. You haven't
    // even waited for the connection to be open before you've disconnected it.
    mongoose.disconnect();
};
```

The reason you pass a callback function to `mongoose.connect` is because `mongoose.connect` is asynchronous. What this means is that your `mongoose.connect` returns ***immediately*** after you call it and your program moves onto the next call. Meanwhile mongoose is now busy connecting to the database which takes a few seconds usually. When it's done connecting it must invoke the callback you passed in. This is how you pass in logic that will be executed at a later time when mongoose is done.

Essentially you called `mongoose.connect` and then `mongoose.disconnect` pretty much immediately. I'm not even sure your callback to `mongoose.connect` would get called if you called `disconnect` before it was done connecting.

Also, I should point out that this:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@(myIP):27017/blog', function (err) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    // connection is now open.
});
```

is exactly the same as:

```
mongoose.connection.once('open', function () {
    // connection is now open.
});
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@(myIP):27017/blog');
```

Ideally in a web application you would connect to your database at application start.

```
var http = require('http');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connection.once('open', function () {

    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('Hello World\n');
    }).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');

}):

mongoose.connect(connectionString);
```

Comment: I used that mongoose.connection.once('open') thing because I saw it in a different SO threat with roughly the same topic. I moved the initial connect to the initial server creation and I removed the disconnect entirely. It seems to be working as expected now. Thanks.

Comment: Good I'm glad you got it working. If you're ever looking for an even simpler setup with mongoose so you don't have to think about that stuff anymore then check out my [mongoose-simpledb](https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose-simpledb) module. Just glance at the readme and you'll immediately see how much it simplifies getting started with mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

You should only be calling

```
mongoose.connection.once(...
```

one time, and not every time a http post is received (I usually call it in the main app.js file and have it start my node/express app upon successful return).  In your createpost function you should only have

```
  var p = new Post({ title: newTitle,
                       content: newContent });
    p.save(function(err){
      if (err) throw err;
    });
```